# Magento 2 Layered Navigation Not Working

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento-2.0.2, multiple-select-layered

I'm using Mageplaza Layered Navigation, with Porto theme for Magento 2 CE.
The problem is that when I select any filters in the product list page, it keeps displaying all the products irrespective of the filters applied.

Although, on the top it shows the message with correct number of products (x items found) as per applied filter.

I ensured Mageplaza Layered Navigation module is enabled, tried clearing cache, re-indexing etc but nothing worked.

Magento Version : 2.0.2
Porto Version : 2.4.2.1

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi shashi009 , I have enabled infinite scroller in backend, but it failed to load the products for some categories. do u have any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update Magento and Porto (if you still have their support).

Magento 2.0.X has a lot of issues and so does Porto at that version.

You could also try disabling Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation from Admin configuration or simply switching to Luma theme and check if layered navigation works.

That would help you determine if it's a default Magento 2.0.2 bug or Mageplaza issue at that version which might help you track down a fix.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Upgrading to Magento 2.1.x solved the issue.